# $H^1$-conforming finite elements

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces, finite-element-method

Let us consider $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$, $d=2,3$ polyhedral domain, i.e. $\bar{\Omega}$ is the union of a finite number of polyhedra.

Let $\bar{\Omega}=\bigcup_{K\in\mathcal{T}_h}K$, where $\mathcal{T}_h$ is a triangulation of simplexes.

I want to prove the following result.

> A function $v:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ belongs to $H^1\left(\Omega\right)$
>   if and only if
>
> - $v|_{K}\in H^1\left(K\right)$ for each $K\in\mathcal{T}_h$,
> - $v|_{K}\in H^1\left(K\right)$ for each $K\in\mathcal{T}_h$, for each common face $F=K_1\cap K_2$, $K_1,K_2\in\mathcal{T}_h$, the trace
>     of $v|_{K_1}$ and $v|_{K_2}$ on $F$ is the same.

I proved the reverse implication "$\leftarrow$", but I have troubles with the other one.

Assume $v\in H^1\left(K\right)$. We have, of course, that $v|_{K}\in H^1\left( K\right)$ for each $K\in\mathcal{T}_h$, which implies that the trace on $F$ is well defined. We need to prove that the last statement about the traces holds.

Any ideas?

I know that I should end up with
$$
\sum_F\int_F\left({v}|_{K_1}-{v}|_{K_2} \right)\varphi n_j=0
$$
for every $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)$.

Comment: What you are trying to prove should be $\int_\Omega v \, \partial_j \varphi = -\sum_K \int_K \partial_j(v|_K) \, \varphi$. This is possible using integration by parts.

Comment: Such sobolev functions are absolutely continuous along lines, and thus cannot jump in the interior of the domain. As such the restrictions to the the interior edges are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a generic  $\varphi\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$.

1. The functional $T:H^1(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
   $$T(v) := \sum_F \int_F (v\vert_{K_1}-v\vert_{K_2})\varphi n_j dS$$
   is continuous.
2. $C^\infty (\bar{\Omega})$ is in the kernel of $T$ and is dense in
   $H^1(\Omega)$.

Thus, $H^1(\Omega)$ is in the kernel of $T$, too.